# Contact list and chat box disappeared

Tags: gmail

My contact list and chatbox has suddenly disappeared from the left hand side of Googlemail. It has disappeared on both my desktop and laptop computers.  Chat is on, browser is good, black box at bottom checked...still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply turned off chat in error?

What happens when you click the "Chat" icon (the one that looks like a speech bubble)?

[image: icons on bottom left of Gmail]